# Can you "pin" an object in memory with Go?

Tags: go

I have a Go object whose address in memory I would like to keep constant. in C# one can pin an object's location in memory. Is there a way to do this in Go?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

An object on which you keep a reference won't move. There is no handle or indirection, and the address you get is permanent.

From [the documentation](http://golang.org/doc/effective_go.html) :

> Note that, unlike in C, it's perfectly OK to return the address of a
>   local variable; the storage associated with the variable survives
>   after the function returns

When you set a variable, you can read this address using the `&` operator, and you can pass it.

Comment: To clarify: Go's GC is not a compacting GC. It will never move live objects around.

Comment: Here's a blogpost (disclaimer: which I wrote) that looks into Go's escape analysis a bit more closely: http://www.scvalex.net/posts/29/

Comment: Stack variable can be moved after Go 1.3, see https://play.golang.org/p/mxZdSK1dcS6

Comment: While the current GC in the go runtime does not move objects in the heap, there is no guarantee that future versions won't move objects on the heap, or that alternate implementations don't. Also objects on the stack can be moved. See my answer below for details.

Comment: This promise is apparently not strong enough for `cgo`, which will not let you pass to C a  pointer to Go memory that itself contains a pointer to Go memory (e.g. you cannot pass a pointer to the type `struct { []byte }` to C).

Answer (score 2):

tl;dr no - but it does not matter unless you're trying to do something unusual.

Worth noting that the accepted answer is partially incorrect.

There is no guarantee that objects are not moved - either on the stack or on the Go heap - but as long as you don't use `unsafe` this will not matter to you because the Go runtime will take care of transparently updating your pointers in case an object is moved.

If OTOH you use `unsafe` to obtain a `uintptr`, invoke raw syscalls, perform CGO calls, or otherwise expose the address (e.g. `oldAddr := fmt.Sprintf("%p", &foo)`), etc. you should be aware that addresses can change, and that nor compiler nor runtime will magically patch things for you.

While currently the standard Go compiler only moves objects on the stack (e.g. when a goroutine stack needs to be resized), there is nothing in the Go language specification that prevents a different implementation from moving objects on the Go heap.

While there is ([yet](https://github.com/golang/go/issues/46787)) no explicit support for pinning objects in the stack or in the Go heap, there is a [recommended](https://github.com/golang/go/issues/12416#issuecomment-136445979) workaround: allocate manually the memory outside of the Go heap (e.g. via `mmap`) and using finalizers to automatically free that allocation once all references to it are dropped. The benefit of this approach is that memory allocated manually outside of the Go heap will never be moved by the Go runtime, so its address will never change, but it will still be deallocated automatically when it's not needed anymore, so it can't leak.

Comment: There is also [a proposal](https://github.com/golang/go/issues/46787) to develop an explicit pinning mechanism.

Comment: Added link to proposal

Answer (score 1):

**tldr** : use runtime.Pinner

it can and there is indeed such a need in some special scenarios.

For example, if you want to avoid the gc overhead of go as much as possible, you might choose to implement a buffer or arena-like structure yourself, based on the unix.mmap and unix.mummap implementations, or to use cgo.

I'm in such a situation at work right now, where I'm using one of these data structures to modify the way a parser-tree creates new nodes, with the key to the modification being to make the memory for creating new nodes come from c (a.k.a. cgo) instead of go.

```golang
type CStr struct {
    o string
    c string
}

func NewCStr(str string, lower int64, buf *buffer.Buffer) *CStr {
    // cs := new(CStr)
    cs := buffer.Alloc[CStr](buf)
    
    cs.o = str
    if lower == 0 {
        cs.c = cs.o
        return cs
    }
    cs.c = strings.ToLower(cs.o)
    return cs
}
```

But this constructor runs into problems, when you run the check with cgocheck=2, you run into problems similar to the following.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Vuecb.jpg)

This is because strings are also pointers, and pointers point to non-go memory, because gc doesn't scan that memory, which means that gc doesn't know that the strings are referenced, and so they may be garbage collected.

```golang
...
    // If the object is pinned, it's safe to store it in C memory. The GC
    // ensures it will not be moved or freed.
    if isPinned(src) {
        return
    }
...
```

https://github.com/golang/go/blob/master/src/runtime/cgocheck.go#L54

Want these go objects not to be recycled, you need to pin, and go now provides this mechanism, accordingly, cgocheck detection logic also has a corresponding place

This is my first time answering a question, and English is not my first language, so please let me know if there are any awkward phrases or factual errors, thanks!

for more info : https://github.com/golang/go/issues/12416

Comment: Looks like `runtime.Pinner` allocates it's argument to the heap. You can keep that in mind if variable escaping to the heap isn't what you want.