# dereference pointer to DB in struct

Tags: go

Usually when I see a field declared on a struct it's without a pointer or a dereferenced pointer symbol *, however in several code snippets where I've seen a database field in a struct it's with a pointer dereference as you see below. Why is that necessary?

```
type DB struct {
    *bolt.DB
}
func Open(path string, mode os.FileMode) (*DB, error) {
    db, err := bolt.Open(path, mode)
    if err != nil {
        return nil, err
    }
    return &DB{db}, nil
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> or a dereferenced pointer symbol *

That is the norm, for complex non-value type, in order to avoid making a copy.
See [Golang book "Pointers"](http://www.golang-book.com/8/index.htm) for example of struct with pointer(s) in them.

```
return &DB{db}
```

That returns a pointer to the newly created `DB` instance.
As noted in "[Can you “pin” an object in memory with Go?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12098718/6309)":

> Note that, unlike in C, it's perfectly OK to return the address of a local variable; the storage associated with the variable survives after the function returns

From "[Pointer/Value Subtleties](http://jmoiron.net/blog/pointer-value-subtleties/)":

> Go is also pass by value, but it has both pointers and value types. Pointers refer to a certain memory location, and allow you to mutate the data at that location

---

For more, see "[Best practice “returning” structs in Go?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/23551970/6309)"

> Use pointers for big structs or structs you'll have to change, and otherwise use values, because getting things changed by surprise via a pointer is confusing.

Comment: thanks, so what makes it a "complex non-value type"?

Comment: @Leahcim this is addressed in http://stackoverflow.com/a/23551970/6309: Small structs like type `Point struct { latitude, longitude float64 }` don't need pointer. Anything bigger than that could need pointer to avoid copy.